# Should semantics be valued higher than code reuse while inheriting classes?

Tags: java, inheritance

If working with inheritance should we put emphasis on reducing duplicated code, or is keeping semantics valued more?

I have a class which reuses code from another class but inheriting isn't necessarily correct from a semantic point of view. Assume we have an event system which generates new events if a certain template matches the triggered event. If this is the case a new event is generated based on the trigger and the template.

```
class Event{

    int field1;
    int field2;
    int field3;

    public int someMethod() {};
    protected int annotherMethod{};
}
```

.

```
class TemplateEvent extends Event{

    boolean replaceField1;
    boolean replaceField2;
    boolean replaceField3;

    int delay;
    TimeUnit unit;
    //....

    public boolean match(Event trigger){
        if(! (this.field1.equals(null) || this.field1.equals(trigger.field1)) 
            return false 
        //.....
    }

    public Event toEvent(Event trigger) {
        Event event = new Event();
        event.field1 = replaceField1 ? this.field1 : trigger.field1;
        //...
        return event;
    }
}
```

.

```
class EventManager{

    void sheduleEvent(Event toBeProcessed){

        if(toBeProcessed matches any Template:t){
            scheduleEvent(t.toEvent(toBeProcessed));
        }
        //Execute Event..
    }
}
```

Inheriting has the issue that we can call *sheduleEvent* on *TemplateEvents*. Which works syntactically as all the information is present and such an event can be processed but does not comply with the logic of it being only a template and no executable event.
Do we in this case declare Event as an abstract class and implement an empty EventImpl class to change our method signature? I have never seen a class implementing an abstract class without making any changes to it beforehand.

Comment: A TemplateEvent (which should probably named EventTemplate, BTW) is not an Event. Ergo, it should not extend Event. Inheritance is not so much about code reuse. It's first and foremost about polymorphism. Your Template could howerver **have** an Event, or an EventState (that Event would also have), serving as a template/prototype for creating other events.

Comment: You create an `interface Event` that is handled by the manager and do the code sharing using an abstract class with implementing subclasses.